# Installing Oracle 11g R2 in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: oracle11g, ubuntu-10.04

## Initial Problem

I was installing **Oracle 11g Release 2** Enterprise edition in **Ubuntu 10.04** ( running on VMWARE ). Need help regarding that.

**Problem #1:**

I was following

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1115155
- http://www.pythian.com/news/13291/installing-oracle-11gr2-enterprise-edition-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/

Both are recommending to install

- libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- ia32-libs_2.7ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb

But I'm getting a 404 to when applying `wget`

Problem 2:

I skipped this part to see the end and finally I'm stuck on running below commands

```
$ cd database
$ ./runInstaller
```

Its throwing error like

```
/opt/database/runInstaller: 153: /opt/database/install/.oui: Permission denied
```

## Problem Phase 2

Thnx **Sathya** 
Finally I could get rid of *Initial Problem*. It was silly permission problem. But now stuck in another. When im running

```
./runInstaller
```

first it is showing following failure

```
Checking Temp space: must be greater than 80 MB.   Actual 10055 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 894 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
>>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<
```

If I ignore this check and press y to continue, it shows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:821)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:804)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:122)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:242)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1783)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:480)
    at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:758)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:164)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:265)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:114)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:132)
```

As my ubuntu is running on VMWARE, may be its not getting the display properties properly.
Also as a clarification
I m doing

```
DISPLAY=oracle:0.0 ; export DISPLAY
```

here *oracle* is the output of

```
whoami
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: **@finding_1:** This problem occurs only from `oracle` user. If I try the same with default user account, everything works just fine. But i need this from oracle user :(
**@finding_2:** `xter, xclock` are not working in oracle user but work in default user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally I got it fixed. 
using

```
xhost +
```

Now I can see that this was recommended in different forums. However, lets include the steps here also :)

1. log into console as root and open a terminal window within CDE
2. `DISPLAY=:0.0`
3. `export DISPLAY`
4. `xhost +`
5. `su - oracle`
6. `DISPLAY=:0.0`
7. `export DISPLAY`
8. `/user/openwin/bin/xclock`  - Launched xclock this way to ensure it was working, and it was
9. Changed back to the directory where the runInstaller was and launched.

Collected from https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=569326

Comment: I think it's only fair that you mark your answer as accepted, considering that these are the steps that helped you fix your problem

Comment: oh... i was a bit confused to do so
However... thnx :)

Comment: Oh god, Thank you, finally resolved by your help. thanks alot

Comment: Thank you so much I spent like half a day to figure it out and then I read your solution :) very happy

Comment: why I have to run these commands each time when server restarted?

Comment: *Just a quick thought*, how about adding these commands in your bashrc?

Answer (score 1):

FYI for others looking at this and still stuck - I still had the issue:

> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.FailedCould not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed

Even after getting xclock to load (on RHEL) for the oracle user. In the end, my issue was '/usr/bin/xdpyinfo' wasn't installed, I was missing xorg-x11-utils.

http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-list/2007-August/msg02702.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are running database server in command-line mode(runlevel 3),and your client is windows,
you should run an X server on your client machine like [Xming server](http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=156984&filename=Xming-mesa-6-9-0-31-setup.exe)

also if you use Putty to connect to the server,X11 forwarding should be enabled
without any location address changing.
No DISPLAY environment needed.
Putty automatically forwards all x commands from the server to your client machine running Xming server.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Both are recommending to install

This isn't required if you're installing a 32-bit version of Oracle or using a 32-bit version of Ubuntu. (and note: you haven't mentioned which one you're using

> I skipped this part to see the end and finally I'm stuck on running below commands

Have you done as mentioned or skipped the entire steps? Intermediate steps involve creating an `oracle` user & adding the usergroups - seems like you skipped these.

Comment: @Sathiya: i followed the whole step again from the very beginning and this time could successfully run it. But again im stuck on **Second Phase Problem**. Need help again about this...

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using oracle to run the installer as suggested by the manual, you only need to run two commands (run from account with sudo access)

```
DISPLAY=:4.0; export DISPLAY
xhost +SI:local user:oracle
```

After that, go back to the tab with oracle and you should be able to run installer now.